# Ansible create a virtualenv using the venv module

Tags: python-3.x, ansible, python-venv

How can one use Ansible to create a virtualenv using the `venv` module from Python3's standard library?

Manually, one would do this to create a venv (virtual environment):

```
python3 -m venv <venv-name>
```

How do I do this using Ansible?

Comment: @kyslik I have already read the documentation multiple times, searched SO, and tried to make things work on my computer. I am aware of the `virtualenv_command` option in the ansible pip module. However, ansible gives an error that `python3 -m venv` is not a valid command. So I am at loss.

Comment: @kyslik Unfortunately, ansible will throw an error if you don't give pip a name.

Comment: Note that ansible's python 3 support might still be flaky

Answer (score 52):

I ran into the same issue tonight and found that specifying the full path to the interpreter, including the arguments, worked for me (at least it does in `ansible==2.2.2.0`):

```
- pip:
     requirements: /website/requirements.txt
     virtualenv: /opt/website-venv
     virtualenv_command: /usr/bin/python3.6 -m venv
```

or

```
- pip:
    requirements: /opt/project/requirements_prod.txt
    virtualenv: /opt/.virtualenv/project_env
    virtualenv_python: python3
```

Comment: It's important to use full path to the python executable. Otherwise ansible says it can't find it in PATH dirs.

Comment: Just FYI in ansible=2.7 to use python3 -m venv you have to use: virtualenv_command: <path_to_python> -m venv and do not include virtualenv_python. See: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/pip_module.html

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example using Ansible's `command` statement:

```
- name: Create Python virtual environment
  command:
    cmd: python3 -m venv {{ project_path }}/project_venv
    creates: "{{ project_path }}/project_venv"
```

Answer (score -3):

```
# Install specified python requirements in indicated (virtualenv).
- pip:
  requirements: /my_app/requirements.txt
  virtualenv: /my_app/venv
```

If python3 is indeed being flaky, you can specify which version of python you'd like to use:

```
# Install specified python requirements in indicated (virtualenv).
- pip:
  requirements: /my_app/requirements.txt
  virtualenv: /my_app/venv
  virtualenv_command: virtualenv-2.7
```

I think that answers your question.

Comment: Syntax is broken. And you seemingly did not understand the meaning of the remark on Python 3 support. It was not about the version of Python inside the virtualenv, but which version of Python Ansible uses to run its modules. You don't set that in your example.

Comment: I am using the venv module from the python standard library to create virtual environments. Not the virtualenv module.